# How do I convert data from .csv file into a NumPy array and use statistics to find the mean of the data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I want to convert the data from the .csv file into a NumPy array and then find the mean of the data.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import statistics as stat
with open('pima-indians-diabetes.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        x = np.array(row[1])
        z = stat.mean(x)
        print(z)
```

Comment: numpy should have own function to read .csv or .tab data.

Comment: use [numpy.loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) with `delimiter=','`

Answer (score 0):

numpy arrays have a mean method built-in.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> data = [3, 6, 3, 5, 3, 2]
>>> numpy.array(data).mean()
3.6666666666666665
```

To get in the csv, see the genfromtxt function: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

Comment: I attempted to find the mean using the NumPy method, but I got the error "cannot perform reduce with flexible type".

Comment: Thanks Matt VE, that solved my problem.